# At what temperature is ammonia liquid at 1.5 bars?

Tags: temperature, liquids, gas

I would like to know at what temperature ammonia condenses from gaseous form into a liquid, at a pressure of 1.5 bars. I know that at normal 1 bar pressure, ammonia is a liquid between -78 and -33 degrees Celsius, but don’t know the math to work out what the temperature would be at 1.5 bars, and can’t find the answer on the internet. It sounds silly, but try typing the above question into a search engine and you’ll see what I mean.

Comment: See https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/ammonia-pressure-temperature-d_361.html

Comment: [Stack Exchange sites are *not* forums](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107), and the CoC has little to do with what a on-topic question is.

Comment: I hope they know that 1.5 bars is 23 psia. Not everyone is "bilingual".

Answer (score 4):

Using *NIST Reference Fluid Thermodynamic and Transport Properties Database (REFPROP)* – NIST Standard Reference Database 23, Version 9, I found the saturation point of ammonia at equilibrium for a pressure of $p=1.5000\ \mathrm{bar}$ at a temperature of $T=-25.210\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$.

If you still want to "try typing the above question into a search engine", try this one: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=saturation+ammonia+at+1.5+bar which also gives $-25.21\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$.

Answer (score 3):

I found these two sources which seem useful in determining the behavior of ammonia at 1.5 bar (21.76 psia). **Seems like it melts around 196 K and boils around 250 K** (perhaps a little lower) at that pressure. Here's a phase diagram that shows this behavior (1.5 bar is 150 kPa, and you can see that the boiling point will be just under 250 K while the melting point will be around the same temperature as the triple point, just under 200 K). This can then be verified in the table of data provided below (the source where I found the table also included the triple point temperature, 196 K, written above).

[image: This graph shows the behavior of ammonia at 1.5 bar (around 100 kPa). Just under 200 K for melting and around 250 K for boiling (again, slightly under but close).]

[image: This table shows the boiling point of ammonia at 1.6 bar (very close to 1.5 bar) to be 250 K.]

Table from: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/ammonia-gas-liquid-equilibrium-condition-properties-temperature-pressure-boiling-curve-d_2013.html

Graph from: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Pressure-temperature-phase-diagram-of-ammonia-The-dashed-line-is-extrapolated-58_fig1_281290526

edit: Thank you Martin for pointing out that 1.5 bar is 150 kPa. That was a silly mistake.